# bazel could not build anything after i delete some files in my .cache in my home directory

Tags: bazel

I tried to reinstall bazel, so i deleted all the bazel files in the .cache in my home directory. 
After i reinstall bazel using the steps provided on the official website, it always returned me error when i tried to compile something.

the error message is:

```
ERROR:/home/user/..cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/ios_rules.bzl:164:9: name 'coverage_common' is not defined

ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/testing/apple_test_bundle_support.bzl:303:9: name 'coverage_common' is not defined

ERROR: Skipping ':all': while parsing ':all': error loading package '': in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl: in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/ios.bzl: in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/testing/ios_rules.bzl: Extension 'apple/internal/testing/apple_test_bundle_support.bzl' has errors

ERROR: while parsing ':all': error loading package '': in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl: in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/ios.bzl: in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/99057f7f4b9c8642f84cd97e14ed25f4/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/testing/ios_rules.bzl: Extension 'apple/internal/testing/apple_test_bundle_support.bzl' has errors
```

How can i fix these errors?

Comment: what version of bazel did you uninstall, and what version of bazel did you install? It looks like `coverage_common` was introduced in bazel version 0.23.0, so you'll need at least that version so that rules_apple can find `coverage_common`

Comment: bazel shutdown? and than bazel build again?